# Installing programs on Linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

When I tried to install arduino on ubuntu, arduino site says that I can install it through terminal by typing these commands

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino arduino-core
```

And generally in Linux Debian we can install programs using terminal by typing

```
sudo apt-get install ${program-name}
```

The question is how could I know the ${program-name} needed to install without going to the program installation guide to copy the code?

Comment: You can search for packages: http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/160897/how-do-i-search-for-available-packages-from-the-command-line.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191977/how-can-i-find-the-package-that-contains-a-program-in-debian this might also be of use.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for @mm759

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> The apt-cache command line tool is used for searching apt software
>   package cache. In simple words, this tool is used to search software
>   packages, collects information of packages and also used to search for
>   what available packages are ready for installation on Debian or Ubuntu
>   based systems.

**To find out the package name and with it description before installing, use the ‘search‘ flag. Using “search” with apt-cache will display a list of matched packages with short description. Let’s say you would like to find out description of package ‘vsftpd‘, then command would be.**

> **Syntax:**
>
> ```
> apt-cache search SearchTerm
> ```

```
$ apt-cache search vsftpd
```

> ***The possible output would be:***

```
vsftpd - lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security
ccze - A robust, modular log coloriser
ftpd - File Transfer Protocol (FTP) server
yasat - simple stupid audit tool
```

> To find and list down all the packages starting with ‘vsftpd‘, you
>   could use the following command.

```
$ apt-cache pkgnames vsftpd
```

> You may also want to run the results through a more, or even a grep.
>   For instance:

```
apt-cache search firefox | grep plugin
```